# Insert data to database from the multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, foreach

I needed to insert some data to mysql database which is stored in a multi-dimensional array.

I have separate values and ready to put the data to database. It caused the problem that it reported that the part of statement "chccheung.BookingDate(Room,Date,From,To)" is not a correct format/syntax, also it has error nearby "From,To)".

After testing and debugging, I could not find out any solution to solve this problem, can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

```
   open the database connection
   .......
       foreach($Booking as $key => $value){
        $rmID = $key;   
        foreach($value as $format => $array){
            foreach($array as $date => $detail){
                $bookDate = $date; 
                foreach($detail as $period =>$fromTo){
                    if($period=="user"){
                        $user = $fromTo;//$query = "INSERT INTO RmBooking_Applicant(user) VALUES ($fromTo)"; 
                    }
                    if($period=="username"){
                        $userID = $fromTo;//$query = "INSERT INTO RmBooking_Applicant(username) VALUES ($fromTo)"; 
                    }
                    if($period=="from"){
                        $fromTime = $fromTo;//$query = "INSERT INTO BookingDate(From) VALUES ($fromTo)";
                    }
                    if($period=="to"){
                        $toTime = $fromTo;//$query = "INSERT INTO BookingDate(To) VALUES ($fromTo)";
                    }
                }
            }
        }                   
    }
    $bookingInformation = "INSERT INTO testingData.BookingDate(Room,Date,From,To) VALUES($rmID,$date,";
    $bookingInformation .= implode(',', $fromTo);
    $bookingInformation .= ")";
    $applicantDetails = "INSERT INTO testingData.RmBooking_Applicant(username,user) VALUES(";
    $applicantDetails .= implode(',', $userID);
    $applicantDetails .= implode(',', $user);;
    $applicantDetails .= ")";
    ......
    close database connection
```

Comment: Date might be a reserved keyword, try enclosing it within ticks (\`..\`)

Answer (score 2):

`from` and `to` are MySQL reserved keywords. Either wrap them in backticks or use another name for those columns.

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

---

```
"INSERT INTO testingData.BookingDate(Room,Date,`From`,`To`)...
```

---

```
//$query = "INSERT INTO BookingDate(`From`)

//$query = INSERT INTO BookingDate(`To`)...
```

Add error reporting to your files http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

depending on the API used

If PDO, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. `$pdo` being the connection variable used.

If not PDO, use the equivalent in `mysqli_` or `mysql_` it's unclear which MySQL API you are using.

`or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`
`or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Either way use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the top of your files.